# Do SQLITE support query on XML?

Tags: android, ios, xml, sqlite, rdbms

I have a situation where I have a well-structured XML with some complex data.
This data needs to be saved temporarily on the device(android-ios based). Instead of parsing the data and saving it every time, can I do query directly on the XML from SQLITE?

I want to provide XML file to SQLITE and do a query on the XML itself.
Is there a way I can do it on android and ios based devices?

**UPDATE: 1**
How can I use xpath/xslt in Android and iOS to query on XML?

**UPDATE: 2**
Anything like http://kasper.eobjects.org/2008/11/how-to-query-xml-file-as-if-it-was.html available in android and ios?

Moderators/Senior-Contributors, please do not close/block this question. I couldn't find a solution I am looking for. This is important.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no direct call to XML. You need to implement your XML parser depending on the structure of your XML. Once your parser is ready you can convert it to your Data Models like POJO/Bean and then write your own wrapper on top of native SQLiteHelper to store and retrieve sql data.

Comment: as said, I don't want to do this. data will be temporarily present and frequently changes. is there any other way to do some query on XML?

Comment: Then there is no direct API for XML to SQL database converter

Answer (score 0):

an query language (RDBMS) helps you in querying on table structure, here you have XML which is not a good idea to be used in query of sql/sqllite  unless otherwise it is converted to table form data.

since this is temp date try data fetch by XPATH, XSLT, XQUERY or similar ones which are ment be be is for this kind of data

For IOS you don't have direct HTML/XML parser to do above (kind of streaming is present), so try using third party libs like GDATA

Check below
http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

For simpler one 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Comment: Can you give me some examples apart from basic w3school's  on how to do that in Android and iOS?

Comment: check this things out - http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project